# Node.js NPM install

Tags: node.js

I was trying out angularJS tutorial listed on their website for creating a phonecat app. it asked me to install a couple of things git, nodejs etc which I did simply by going to their respective websites and downloading the installer and running it. Now at one point in the beginning it says after the installation of nodejs, I have to run npm install in the command prompt which will automatically download bower, karma, protractor, http-server.

Now the problem is whenever I run npm install from either nodejs command prompt or windows cmd it gives tons of errors. I don't think I have an installation error I simply ran the installer.
Can someone help out, please?
error is:

> - npm err install couldn't read dependencies
> - npm err windows_nt 6.1.7601
> - npm err argv "C:\program files\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\progam files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" "install"
> - npm err node v0.12.1
> - npm err npm v2.5.1
> - npm err path c:\users\SkyNet\package.json
> - npm err code ENOPACKAGEJSON
> - npm errno -4058
> - npm err package.json ENOENT, open 'c:\users\skynet\package.json'
> - npm err package.json this is most likley not a problem with npm itself.
> - npm err package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory
> - npm err include the following file with an support request
> - npm err c:\users\skynet\npm-debug.log

Answer (score 1):

You're not running the command `npm install` from within a folder that contains a `package.json` file.

There's probably no issue with your node.js installment (as the error suggest)

Navigate to the project folder containing the `package.json and the execute the command.

Comment: There are tons of directories i see here. one i the nodejs folder where it is installed, one is in the c:/users/skynet/AppData/roaming/npm_module and one is in the my document/node_modules. 
Which one should i navigate to?

Comment: i did navigate inside the folder c:/program files/nodejs/node_modules/npm where the package json file was. but on executing npm install again i get even more errors :/

Comment: You need to be in the project folder, not inside the npm or node folders. Your project's root folder should contain a package.json file